# Can I filter input values that match either of 2 regexes?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to filter the numbers using regular expressions. Basically, I want to match:

- `9.0.0.*` and/or
- `*-MVC`

I'm trying to find out if there is a way we can combine the two expressions. In other words, for the following input:

```
1. 319.0-MVC
2. 320.0-MVC
3. 1.1.2.336
4. 8.1.0.337
```

my output should be like:

```
1. 319.0-MVC
2. 320.0-MVC
```

How can I filter according to either pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use alternation:

```
\d+\. (?:9\.0\.0.*|.*-MVC)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tS6wA3/1)

Which will form any line starting with digits + DOT + space and followed by 2 alternating sub-expressions provided in a non-capturing group `(?:...)`.

Comment: anubhava, Thanks you so much. It is working as expected.